# Generalizing Archimedes' "The Quadrature of the Parabola"

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

In the third century BC Archimedes discovered that

> The area enclosed by a parabola and a line (left figure) is 4/3 that of a related inscribed triangle (right figure).

Consequentially, the area enclosed by a parabola and a line is 2/3 that of a parallelogram which has the chord and its tangential-to-the-parabola-copy as two of its sides. I have tried to derive this result myself using calculus.

Suppose $f:I \subseteq \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is a smooth *convex*  function (so that the chord is on a fixed side of the graph), defined over some interval $I$. For $a < b$, let $[a,b] \subseteq I$ be a closed subinterval. The area of the segment bounded by the graph of $f$ and the chord $\overline{(a,f(a)) (b,f(b))}$ is given by
$$\int_a^b \left( f(a)+(t-a) \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} - f(t) \right) \mathrm{d}t. \tag{1}$$
For the areas of the inscribed triangle and related parallelogram, we will use the point $c \in (a,b)$, which has the slope
$$f'(c) =\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$
Such a point exists according to the MVT, and it is unique because of the convexity of $f$. Thus
$$c = c(a,b)= f'^{-1} \left( \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right). $$
The area of the aforementioned parallelogram is then the area between two parallel segments
$$\int_a^b \left[ f(a)+(t-a) \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} - \left( f(c)+(t-c) \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right) \right] \mathrm{d}t.$$

Archimedes' result implies that

$$
\begin{align}&\int_a^b \left( f(a)+(t-a) \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} - f(t) \right) \mathrm{d}t \\
&= 
k \int_a^b \left[ f(a)+(t-a) \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} - \left( f(c)+(t-c) \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right) \right] \mathrm{d}t
\end{align} \tag{3}$$

for $f(x)=x^2$, $a<b$, $c(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $k=\frac{2}{3}$.

My questions are about going in reverse:

1. Is it possible to systematically arrive at $f(x)=x^2$ (or a similar parabola), starting off with knowledge that $f$ is convex over some interval, $f$ satisfies Equation $(3)$ for all subintervals $[a,b]$ of its domain and $k=\frac{2}{3}$?
2. Is it possible to generalize this result by solving Equation $(3)$ for $k \neq \frac{2}{3}$ (clearly, $k \leq 1$)? I would appreciate guidance on how to do this if possible.

Thanks!

[image]  [image]

Comment: Hey, I made those images like ten years ago!

Comment: @Bonnaduck Thank you for that. They are very helpful to me.

Comment: @Bonnaduck Should you also not have  included tangent line parallel to given slant line ( at the lowest point of blue triangle)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's rewrite $(3)$ with $a=x$, $b=x+h$ and consider $c$ as a function of $h$ (for a fixed $x$):
$$
\tag{*}
{h\over2}(f(x+h)+f(x))-\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt=
k\big[-h[f(c)-f(x)]+(c-x)[f(x+h)-f(x)]\big].
$$
We can differentiate both sides of $(*)$ with respect to $h$
a certain number of times
(I'm supposing functions $f$ and $c$ are sufficiently regular), 
substituting then each time: 
$$
f'(c)= {f(x + h) - f(x)\over h},\quad c'(h)={h f'(x + h) - f(x + h) + f(x)\over h^2 f''(c)}
$$
(the second equation can be obtained by differentiating the first one), 
and in the end take the limit of both sides for $h\to0$ (remembering that $c(0)=x$).

We obtain the first non-trivial equation after differentiating three times: I won't write down the intermediate result, which is quite long and complicated, but taking the limit $h\to0$ gives a simple result:
$$
{1\over2}f''(x)=k{3\over4}f''(x),
$$
which is satisfied either by $f''(x)=0$ (trivial solution: a straight line) or by $k=2/3$.

> Hence it is not possible to solve equation (*) with $k\ne2/3$.

Substituting now $k=2/3$ into $(*)$ and differentiating five times with respect to $h$, as before, the limit for $h\to0$ gives this differential equation:
$$
\tag{**}
f^{(4)}(x)={5\over3}{\big(f^{(3)}(x)\big)^2\over f''(x)}.
$$
This has the particular solution $f^{(3)}(x)=0$, which gives a parabola:

$$\tag{#}
f(x)=\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma,
$$

while the general solution is:

$$\tag{§}
f(x) = \alpha \sqrt{x + \beta} + \gamma x + \delta,
$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ are arbitrary constants. But it is easy to see that the graph of $(§)$ is again an arc of a parabola, with equation:
$(y-\gamma x-\delta)^2=\alpha^2(x + \beta)$.

> Hence the parabola is the only non-straight curve obeying Archimedes' 
>   relation in the form given in the question as equation $(3)$.
>   However, as a function, it can be written either in the form
>   $(\text{#})$ or in the form $(§)$ given above.

Comment: Great handling of the equation! I followed your methodology, and I think you got the RHS of equation $(*)$ slightly wrong. I believe it should be $k$ times $(c-x)(f(x+h)-f(x))-h(f(c)-f(x))$. Other than that I also got that same ODE leading to the same conclusions. Thank you.

Comment: @user1337 Thank you for pointing out that typo! Just corrected.